# awscli DescribeUserPoolClient doesn't return almost anything despite the documentation it should return all appClient settings

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-cognito, aws-cli

I'm trying to run DescribeUserPoolClient through python code and also through cloudshell, and this command doesn't return almost anything:

```
{
"UserPoolClient": {
    "UserPoolId": "id",
    "ClientName": "name",
    "ClientId": "id",
    "ClientSecret": "secret",
    "LastModifiedDate": "2021-05-10T14:21:24.733000+00:00",
    "CreationDate": "2021-05-10T14:21:24.733000+00:00",
    "RefreshTokenValidity": 30,
    "TokenValidityUnits": {},
    "AllowedOAuthFlows": [
        "client_credentials"
    ],
    "AllowedOAuthScopes": [
        ":write"
    ],
    "AllowedOAuthFlowsUserPoolClient": true
}
```

}
This is only parameters it returns. But documentation says that there should be a lot more like "ExplicitAuthFlows" and others. Is there something with aws or maybe something with my access rights?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone having trouble with the same issue: If you have any property set by default and never touched it (never edited) amazon won't return them in request. This works for many other aws cli commands also.
Maybe it is common knowledge, but i struggled with it)